# open and close different levels of a submenu on click

Tags: jquery, nested-lists

I have a premade menu that cannot be changed. The menu is made up from nested lists on three levels. I want to open only that part where a parent-element is clicked.

Here my HTML:

```
  <ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li>Black tea</li>
      <li>Green tea
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li>From India</li>
            <li>From Philippines</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>
```

In the beginnig the whole list is displayed, Therefore I added some code (jquery and CSS) to target the different submenus and have them closed.

```
$(".sub-menu").not(".sub-menu > li > .sub-menu").addClass("closed first_level");
$(".sub-menu > li > .sub-menu").addClass("closed second_level");

.closed {display: none !important;}
.opened {display: block !important;}
```

and now the opening and closing:

```
$( ".first_level" ).parent("li").click(function() {
  $(".first_level").toggleClass("closed opened");
  $(".first_level").slideToggle("slow");
});

$( ".second_level" ).parent("li").click(function() {
  $(".second_level").toggleClass("closed opened");
  $(".second_level").slideToggle("slow");  
});
```

My solution only works half, there are many effects I do not want. The submenus slide up and down bevore they open and other ugly things.

I know my jQuery is a mess, but I am still learning. So can anybody help me please?

Another question: That problem must be quite common. Which would be the right phrase for finding solutions by search engines? I could not find anything that helped me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you will do it like that you will save a lot of code :D
For 1st. code need to find if element is hidden or not, and chose function to show or hide. after 1 step we stop function from execute. 
Why u use `return false`?  to stop code execute without that script will hide/show not only child element, with occur visually error.

I hope i help xD

Anytime you can change animation xD i just put simple slide xD

```js
$("li").on('click',function(){
if($(this).find("ul:first").is(":hidden")){
$(this).find("ul:first").slideDown();
return false;
}
else{
$(this).find("ul:first").slideUp();
return false;
}
  });
```

```css
li ul{
display:none}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li>Black tea</li>
      <li>Green tea
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li>From India</li>
            <li>From Philippines</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>
```

**Some extra:**

Fiddle with append arrow(:D) xD
https://jsfiddle.net/5pxwy0od/

I use siblings, and body click becouse arrows(elements) were created after html(node list) was ready, so elements aren't visible for jquery, each time when we add some element(element node) after DOM render we have to use body as selector. 
Like that:

```
$("body").on('click','.nav_arrow',function(){ 
// function goes here
});
```

Comment: Ups, I forgot something. Sorry. Off course every <li> has a <a> inside. Otherwise the menu would be useless. ;) Your code only works for sliding up and down. (Whis is already very good!) But it stops the links from working. Do you know how to fix this? Would be great if you can help once again!

Comment: IF every li have a A inside you will have some arrows to slide it, im right?? so just simply reproduce my code xD change on click name from li to "name of arrow" and change .find("ul:first") for .next('ul');

Comment: Hi, I tried, but dod not work. Sorry, i am a beginner. ;)

So i added the arrow first by jQuery, because there is none.

Comment: Thank, but does not work. Must be a mistake somewhere. 
what I did: 

1) I add the arrow, because there is no arrow included. That works. 
$("li.menu-item-has-children").prepend( "<div class='nav_arrow'></div>" );

I do not quote the CSS here, because it is not that much important. anyway it works. 
. 
But the other stuff did not work. : 
$(".nav_arrow").on('click',function(){
if($(this).next("ul").is(":hidden")){
$(this).next("ul").slideDown();
return false;
}
else{
$(this).next("ul").slideUp();
return false;
}
  }); 


Any idea where is the bug? 
Thanks

Comment: if you are adding element using jquery not just putting it as html... .nav.arrow wont work... becouse element not exist... you have to do it by body.... send me fiddle and i will help

Comment: Thank you for helping. Can you look at homepage-4-you.net/saxotex-testumgebung/ It is a premade theme, So i cannot create a fiddle out of it. The "arrow" which is a yellow square just now, is in the source code. If I can target :before or :after, I can rebuild it. if there is no mistake in my code, that would be enough. 

I could also create a constrction with ":before", but I was not sure if i can target the :before element in jquery.

Comment: sorry your page aren't protected... just copy your code and put on fiddle. just put menu not whole template...  it is just copy and paste :D if you are making arrows from css put css code also xD

Comment: OK, I created a fiddle. ;) https://jsfiddle.net/rabox66/duty8pcq/16/ 
Thank you for helping!

Comment: Done :D everything in my answer

Answer (score 0):

I also added Arrows to indicate the state of opening/ closing. My whole code is stored in that fiddle, here just the jQuery if anyone else wants to use it:

```
$("body").on('click','.nav_arrow',function(){ 
/* alert($(this).closest('ul').html()); */
if($(this).siblings(".sub-menu").is(":hidden"))
   { $(this).siblings(".sub-menu").slideDown(); 
    $(this).addClass("turn"); return false;
}
else{ $(this).siblings(".sub-menu").slideUp(); 
$(this).removeClass("turn"); return false; } 
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rabox66/duty8pcq/28/

Hope it is OK, anyway it works. ;)